# how to show value of one page to another page in php?

Tags: php

I have two pages like reg.php and profile.php. in reg.php have a field gender want to show on profile.php. i get gender field from reg.php on profile.php.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A litle Sample to use a HTML Form for subimting data ....

reg.php

```
<form action="profile.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test" value="Test" />
<input type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST["test"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

- Use a hidden form field and submit the form to profile.php.
- Append the field to the URL like this: `profile.php?gender=male`.
- Put the field in the user's [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).
- Put the field in a database, and retrieve it from the database in profile.php.

Comment: Can u plz send me test file of php?